# Introspección en python: atributos de clase hija no presentes en clase base

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un pequeño ORM para un proyecto personal, exclusivo para SQLite. La idea es tener una clase `Table` y heredar de ella una clase por cada tabla usada.

El objetivo es que cada clase hija defina una serie de atributos que hacen referencia a los campos de la tabla; la clase base interpretará esos atributos y generará las sentencias SQL correspondientes. Algo así:

```
class Table:
    PK = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY'
    STRING = 'STRING'
    INTEGER = 'INTEGER'
    NN = 'NOT NULL'
    NULL = 'DEFAULT NULL'

class Files( Table ):
    uid = Table.PK
    path = ( Table.STRING, Table.NN )
    pathHash = ( Table.INTEGER, Table.NN )
    write = ( Table.INTEGER, Table.NN )
    size = ( Table.INTEGER, Table.NN )
    sha1 = ( Table.STRING, Table.NN )
```

Para que esto funcione, necesito obtener los atributos **exclusivos de la clase hija**; es decir, aquellos que no están presentes en la clase base.

- ¿ Como puedo obtener los atributos exclusivos de la clase hija ?

Answer (score 3):

Interesante pregunta, y aunque la auto-respuesta de @Trauma cumple con lo que se pedía, hay algunos puntos que se pueden mejorar/simplificar.

1. No veo necesario usar `globals()`. Las soluciones que requieren usar `globals()` son raras y obedecen al hecho de que se tiene el *nombre* de una variable en lugar de tener referencias al objeto apuntado. En este caso queremos una refrencia al tipo de la clase hija, lo que se obtiene con `type(self)`. Puesto que ya tenemos esa referencia, es absurdo usarla para sacar de ella el nombre (tirando de `.__name__`) para después usar ese nombre como clave en `globals()` para volver a obtener la referencia que de todas formas ya teníamos.
2. Los miembros de la clase hija que no están en la clase base son simplemente la resta de lo que hay en la hija menos lo que hay en la base. No hay necesidad de añadirle luego la resta de la base menos la hija (aparte de que esta diferencia será vacía, pues todo lo que está en la base estará en la hija)

Así que el código se simplificaría de este modo:

```py
class Table:
    PK = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY'
    STRING = 'STRING'
    INTEGER = 'INTEGER'
    NN = 'NOT NULL'
    NULL = 'DEFAULT NULL'

    def __init__( self ):
        miembros_hija = set(dir(type(self)))
        miembros_base = set(dir(Table))
        members = list(miembros_hija - miembros_base)
        print( members )
```

Por otro lado no necesitas escribir un constructor para la clase hija si la única función del mismo es invocar el constructor de la clase base. Ese constructor por defecto ya te lo hace python. Así que la clase hija podría quedar así:

```py
class Files( Table ):
    uid = Table.PK
    path = ( Table.STRING, Table.NN )
    pathHash = ( Table.INTEGER, Table.NN )
    write = ( Table.INTEGER, Table.NN )
    size = ( Table.INTEGER, Table.NN )
    sha1 = ( Table.STRING, Table.NN )
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

```
>>> f = Files()
['pathHash', 'write', 'uid', 'size', 'path', 'sha1']
```

Answer (score 2):

Podemos usar las capacidades de introspección de `python` para obtener lo que buscamos:

- [`type( )`](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=type#type) nos devuelve el tipo de un determinado objeto, pudiendo así acceder a sus atributos.
- [`globals( )`](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=type#globals) nos devuelve una referencia al espacio de nombres *global*, en el cual existen todos los módulos y todos los tipos definidos.
- [`dir( )`](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=type#dir) nos devuelve una lista de atributos válidos para el objeto indicado.

Ahora, podemos colocar el código en el constructor **de la clase base (`Table`)**, de forma que se automatice todo:

```
class Table:
    PK = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY'
    STRING = 'STRING'
    INTEGER = 'INTEGER'
    NN = 'NOT NULL'
    NULL = 'DEFAULT NULL'

    def __init__( self ):
        self._tableName = ( type( self ).__name__ )
        base = globals( )[self._tableName]
        selfMembers = dir( base )
        baseMembers = dir( Table )
        members = list( set( selfMembers ) - set( baseMembers ) ) + list( set( baseMembers ) - set( selfMembers ) )

        print( members )


class Files( Table ):
    uid = Table.PK
    path = ( Table.STRING, Table.NN )
    pathHash = ( Table.INTEGER, Table.NN )
    write = ( Table.INTEGER, Table.NN )
    size = ( Table.INTEGER, Table.NN )
    sha1 = ( Table.STRING, Table.NN )

    def __init__( self ):
        super( ).__init__( )

files = Files( )
```

Lo anterior muestra en pantalla:

> ['size', 'path', 'write', 'pathHash', 'uid', 'sha1']

Es decir, justo lo que buscabamos: la lista de atributos **exclusivos de la clase hija (`Files`)**. Con lo cual ya podríamos, desde el constructor de la clase base (`Table`), hacer todas las operaciones que queramos.

Por ejemplo, ayudándonos del módulo [`types`](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/types.html), podemos añadir funciones que ejecuten las sentencias `SQL` necesarias:

```
import types


def getter( self ):
    print( 'getter', type( self ) )


class Table:
    def __init__( self ):
        self._tableName = ( type( self ).__name__ )
        base = globals( )[self._tableName]
        selfMembers = dir( base )
        baseMembers = dir( Table )
        members = list( set( selfMembers ) - set( baseMembers ) ) + list( set( baseMembers ) - set( selfMembers ) )

        for item in members:
            self.__dict__[f'get{item}'] = types.MethodType( getter, self )


class Files( Table ):
    uid = Table.PK

    def __init__( self ):
        super( ).__init__( )
```

Ya tenemos la *magia*: desde el constructor **de la clase base (`Table`)** se han añadido métodos **a la clase hija (`Files`)**, uno por cada atributo de esta última no presente en la clase base:

```
files = Files( )
files.getuid( )
```

> getter <class '**main**.Files'>

Comment: Otra cosa, no entiendo por qué añades a members lo que va tras el `+` ¿no es eso los miembros de la clase base que no están en la hija? Entiendo que ese conjunto será siempre vacío, y aún si no fuera el caso no creo que quieras tenerlo en la lista members. Y si realmente quieres, entonces lo que estás calculando puede simplificarse con el operador ^ (xor entre conjuntos, que resulta en la unión menos la intersección). O sea: `members = list(set(selfMembers) ^ set(baseMember ) )`. De todas formas sale lo mismo, porque la unión es igual a `selfMembers` porque la hija tiene todo lo de la base

Comment: @abulafia jejeje ... muy sencillo; porque me ha costado 1 hora juntar los diversos *cachos* de información que he podido reunir hasta conseguir lo que buscaba. Sabes que apenas me manejo en `python`. ¿ Publicas una respuesta con tus cambios ?

Answer (score 1):

Una solución:

```
set(dir(Files)).difference(set(dir(Table)))
```

La función `dir()` retorna los atributos de cada clase, con los que construimos dos *set*.

El método `difference` nos da todos los atributos del primer set (`Files`) que no están en el segundo (`Table`).

*Demo*

```
class Table:
    PK = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY'
    STRING = 'STRING'
    INTEGER = 'INTEGER'
    NN = 'NOT NULL'
    NULL = 'DEFAULT NULL'

class Files( Table ):
    uid = Table.PK
    path = ( Table.STRING, Table.NN )
    pathHash = ( Table.INTEGER, Table.NN )
    write = ( Table.INTEGER, Table.NN )
    size = ( Table.INTEGER, Table.NN )
    sha1 = ( Table.STRING, Table.NN )


print(set(dir(Files)).difference(set(dir(Table))))
```

produce:

```
{'path', 'size', 'pathHash', 'uid', 'sha1', 'write'}

Process finished with exit code 0
```